# How to implement this simple algorithm elegantly in Scala

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I would like to have an elegant implementation of the method with the following (or similar) signature:

```
def increasingSubsequences(xs: List[Int]): List[List[Int]]
```

What it does is it splits the input sequence without reordering the elements so that every subsequence in the result is strictly increasing.

I implemented it myself as follows:

```
  def increasingSubsequences(list: List[Int], temp: List[Int] = Nil, res: List[List[Int]] = Nil): List[List[Int]] = {
    (list, temp) match {
      case (x :: xs, t :: ts) if t < x => increasingSubsequences(xs, x :: temp, res)
      case (x :: xs, Nil) => increasingSubsequences(xs, List(x), res)
      case _ if list.nonEmpty => increasingSubsequences(list, Nil, temp.reverse :: res)
      case _ if temp.nonEmpty => (temp.reverse :: res).reverse
      case _ => res.reverse
    }
  }
```

Although the above code is not very long, I would like to see a more elegant and concise solution if possible (possibly by using combinators).

**Sample input and output:**

```
List(5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 8, 5) —> List(List(5, 6), List(2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 6, 8), List(5))
List() —> List()
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) —> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
List(5, 4, 3, 2, 1) —> List(List(5), List(4), List(3), List(2), List(1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reversing the list and then using `foldLeft`.

```
def increasingSubsequences(list: List[Int]) = list.reverse.foldLeft(List[List[Int]]()) {
  case (a :: as, b) if b < a.head => (b :: a) :: as   // same subsequence
  case (as, b)                    => List(b)  :: as   // new subsequence
}
```

Comment: Thank you, magnificent piece of code. Please accept my edit suggestion (your original code returns List(List()) instead of Nil for Nil input.

Answer (score 1):

Using [scalaz's groupWhen](https://static.javadoc.io/org.scalaz/scalaz_2.12/7.2.17/scalaz/std/ListFunctions.html#groupWhen%5BA%5D%28as%3AList%5BA%5D%29%28p%3A%28A%2CA%29%3D%3EBoolean%29%3AList%5Bscalaz.NonEmptyList%5BA%5D%5D), it's fairly simple:

```
import scalaz.std.list._

def increasingSubsequences(xs: List[Int]) = groupWhen(xs)(_ < _)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very useful. I gave you a +1, however, I accepted @LRLucena's answer as he only uses the core library.

Answer (score 0):

I think this fits the bill for what you want.  It does use an `if-else` clause that could be refactored into another match statement, but I didn't like how it looked that way.  Without using a helper method, I can't think of a nice way to make it tail recursive, sadly.

```
def increasingSubsequences(xs: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
  xs match {
    case Nil => List(Nil) //in case someone calls on empty list
    case (head :: Nil) => List(head :: Nil) //base case
    case (head :: rest) => {
      val finishedRest = increasingSubsequences(rest)
      finishedRest match {
        case ((headOfFirst :: restOfFirst) :: restOfFinished) => {
          if (head < headOfFirst) (head :: headOfFirst :: restOfFirst) :: restOfFinished
          else List(List(head), headOfFirst::restOfFirst) ++ restOfFinished
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are two minor discrepancies from what you specified:

- `List()` produces `List(List())`
- `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` produces `List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

I can only assume you meant to specify these this way, as otherwise, they do not fit the return type of `List[List[Int]]`.*

*I should also mention that the first one is somewhat okay, as Scala doesn't mind the interior `List[Int]` being implied, and it in fact produces that if you change the first case to simply `Nil => Nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this using List's `foldLeft`:

```
def increasingSubsequences(list:List[Int]) =
  list.foldLeft(List[List[Int]]())((accum, value) => {
    accum match {
      case Nil => List(List(value))
      case headList :: tailList => {
        headList match {
          case head :: tail if value > head => List(headList :+ value) ++ tailList
          case _ => List(List(value)) ++ accum
        }
      }
    }
}).reverse
```

As @Dimitri pointed out, complexity MIGHT be better if using `::` and `map(._reverse)`. So, here you go...you can decide :)

```
def increasingSubsequences(list:List[Int]) =
  list.foldLeft(List[List[Int]]())((accum, value) => {
    accum match {
      case Nil => List(List(value))
      case headList :: tailList => {
        headList match {
          case head :: tail if value > head => List(value :: headList) ++ tailList
          case _ => List(List(value)) ++ accum
        }
      }
    }
}).map(_.reverse).reverse
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but in terms of complexity I think `List(value :: headList)` then `.map(_.reverse)` on the final result would be slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def increasingSubsequences(xs: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    val splits = xs.sliding(2).zipWithIndex.toList
      .map { case (sub, i) => if (sub(0) >= sub(1)) i + 1 else -1 } filter (_ > 0)
    (List(0, splits.head) :: splits.sliding(2).toList ++ List(List(splits.last, xs.size)))
      .map { case pos => xs.slice(pos(0), pos(1)) }
  }
```

You can first find all split point, and splits them.